# Remove a view from controller from any other class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have three screens Google Map,Settings,Login.By default google map is visible.When i want to show settings screen then i don't move to settings view controller i just add "Settings"screen as subview of "Google Map"Screen.

```
 menusettings=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SET"];
 [menusettings.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700,600)];
 [self.view addSubview:menusettings.view];
```

After upadating settings i move to login screen

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *ppc = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
[self presentViewController:ppc animated:true completion:nil];
```

But settings screen is still behind login screen but it is not removed. I tried two scenerios

1.I tried to remove settings view before moving to login screen

```
 [self.view removeFromSuperview];
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PRG_iPhone" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *ppc = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
 [self presentViewController:ppc animated:true completion:nil];
```

but it does not move to login screen.

2.When i tried removing settings view after moving to login screen

```
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PRG_iPhone" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *ppc = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
     [self presentViewController:ppc animated:true completion:nil];
     [self.view removefromsuperview];
```

Then it moved to login screen but does not remove settings view

So i thought why not remove Google Map Screen's subview which is **setting screen** from **login screen** but i don't know how can i remove a **google map screen** child view which is settings screen.Please guide how to do this ?

Comment: are you want hide menusettings  view?

Comment: i want to remove menu settings from superview.It is already hidden when login screen appear

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

to and try

```
[menusettings.view removeFromSuperview];
```

**update**

```
  [menusettings.view removeFromSuperview];
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PRG_iPhone" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *ppc = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
 [self presentViewController:ppc animated:true completion:nil];
```

**Choice-1**

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

**choice-2**

Initially assign the tag for your View for e.g

```
menusettings=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SET"];
[menusettings.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700,600)];
 menusettings.tag = 5; //you can use any number you like
[self.view addSubview:menusettings.view];
```

*Remove*

```
 UIView *Remove = [self.view viewWithTag:5];
[Remove removeFromSuperview];
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PRG_iPhone" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *ppc = (UINavigationController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LOGIN"];
 [self presentViewController:ppc animated:true completion:nil];
```

**Choice-3**

```
 for (UIView *subVie in self.view.subviews)
{
    if (subVie.tag == 5) 
    {
        [subVie removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
```

Comment: But i am writing [self.view removefromsuperview] in Settings Class so how can i write [menusettings.view removefromsuperview];

Comment: @deepakkumar - check the **Choice-1** answer

Comment: what it does it removes all views from google map screen.You see google map screen has already views.Only settings screen should be removed not the all views.So with your code it makes Google Map screen white

Comment: @deepakkumar - it remove all subviews , you need to remove only menu view correct

Comment: @deepakkumar - try with Choice -2

Comment: @deepakkumar - check choice-3

Comment: @deepakkumar - are you there ,

Comment: yes,But choice 2 still not working.Where to add choice 3 code

Comment: @deepakkumar - sorry bro, I added the best ways, I dont know your project concept

Comment: can u suggest anything else ?

Comment: @deepakkumar - no deepak, no otehr idea bro

Comment: I am totally stuck suggest something else